# Google Maps marker colour based on database value

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I wish the marker colour on a Google Map to change if the `BusinessType` field in the database for that marker is a certain value.

Currently my map can be filtered for different business types through values in a listbox. The values are `All` (to include everything), `Type1` and `Type2`.

I've used the following to change the marker from the default to a custom graphic which works well but it uses it for all markers, as expected.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: latlng,
    icon: 'BlueMarker.png'
});
```

I've tried various if statements both for the `marker` variable as a whole and just for the `icon` part of the variable but I can't get it to use a different graphic based on the value in the `BusinessType` variable.

Can somebody point me in the right direction please?

This is the entire function for the marker:

```
function createMarker(latlng, name, add1, add2, add3, town, county, address, businesstel, website) {

   var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + add1 + " <br/>"  + add2 + " <br/>" + add3 + " <br/>" + town + " <br/>" + county + " <br/>"
   + address + " <br/>" + " <br/>"+ " <b>" + "Tel: " + businesstel + " </b> <br/>" + "<a href="+"http://www.website.com> <font color="+"blue>"+ website +"</font> </a> <br/> <br/>";

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: latlng,
    icon: 'BlueMarker.png'
  });

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });

markers.push(marker);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: add a variable to keep the icon type, set its value in an if condition then set icon property of the marker to that variable

Comment: That did cross my mind but I thought it should be able to be achieved within the existing variable using an if statement (although I'm a complete newbie to Javascript so what do I know). I have now done it this way so thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit of a stretch (depends on how complex your icon is), but if you're familiar with SVG path notation (http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathData) you can create custom SVG icons and update the `fillColor` property with any available CSS3 color (e.g., `fillColor: 'yellow'` or #990000 - essentially any compatible color that you are returning from your database).

See the official docs for an example (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-symbol-custom).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm new to all this and the solution I was working with seemed the easiest to achieve which I've now done. Maybe I can use your suggested method in a future version. Thanks!